# SlideToggle accordion active element and unbind hover

Tags: jquery, hover, slidetoggle, unbind, gsap

i'm trying to make a content accordion with greensock tweenmax and have some problem to desactivate the hover state and make the clicked element active.

i have a html structure like that :

```
<div id="bienvenue" class="col-sm-12 divContent">
    <div class="divImgBw"><img src="images/bienvenue_bw.png"/></div>
    <div class="divImg"><img src="images/bienvenue.png"/></div>
</div>

<div class="subContent" id="bienvenueContent">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.</p>

    <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate</p>      
</div>
```

where divContent is the element to trigger the slideToggle, the divImgBw class shows the state when nothing is over or clicked, divImg is the state when mouse is over or clicked.

So this is my jquery script :

```
$('.divContent').hover(function(){
    var $divContent = $(this).find('.divImg');
    $($divContent).addClass('grow');
    TweenMax.to($divContent, 0.5, {opacity:1});
},function(){
    var $divContent = $(this).find('.divImg');
    TweenMax.to($divContent, 1, {opacity:0});
});


var $subContent = $('.subContent');
$('.divContent').on('click', function() {

    var $divContent = $(this).find('.divImg');

    if(false == $(this).next().is(':visible')) {
        $subContent.slideUp(300);
        $('.divContent').removeClass('active');
    }

    $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
    $(this).toggleClass('active');


if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
    $(this).off('mouseenter mouseleave');       
    TweenMax.to($divContent, 1, {opacity:1});
} else {
    $(this).on('mouseenter mouseleave');        
    TweenMax.to($divContent, 1, {opacity:0});   
}

});
```

The problem is that i want to unbind the hover states on click and keep the divImg opacity of the selected element to 1 while the others stays inactivated but hoverable. Don't know if i'm clear...my english level is not very good! Anyway i've tried different ways with no success.
You can see the problem here, it will be more understandable : http://www.lepoissonchat.fr/test/

Thank you for the help.

Olivier